# Provenance -- Java error: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, import

This is quite stupid question but I don't really understand why this happens.

I'm learning to use the Provenance toolbox, its API can be found here: 
http://openprovenance.org/java/site/0_6_0/apidocs/index.html

First of all, the `doConversions()` method is used for testing and all these problems are from there.

I'm trying to read a provenance document (.provn) by using method

```
readDocumentFromFile(String filename)
```

and it returns a document. Then I use methods in class Document to get all prov statements and bundle in the document, this returns a list of statements OR bundles in the document.

But when I compile the java file (found below), it throw an error:

```
/home/hduser/Downloads/ProvToolbox-Tutorial1-0.6.1/src/main/java/org/openprovenance/prov/tutorial/tutorial1/Little.java:[17,36] error: cannot find symbol
```

which is the `NamedBundle` class. Can someone explain why does this happen? The NamedBundle class is in package `org.openprovenance.prov.model`

The code is compiled by using command: `mvn clean install` in commandline. Maven version 1.3 is used to compile this code.

Another question: NamedBundle class extends StatementOrBundle class, as you can see from the code, temp.get(i) return an element in `List<StatementOrBundle>`

I want to use methods from NamedBundle class, How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
package org.openprovenance.prov.tutorial.tutorial1;

import java.util.*;

import org.openprovenance.prov.interop.InteropFramework;
import org.openprovenance.prov.interop.InteropFramework.ProvFormat;
//import org.openprovenance.prov.model.*;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.Agent;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.Document;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.Entity;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.Namespace;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.QualifiedName;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.ProvFactory;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.StatementOrBundle;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.WasAttributedTo;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.WasDerivedFrom;
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.NamedBundle;

/**
 * A little provenance goes a long way. 
 * ProvToolbox Tutorial 1: creating a provenance document in Java and serializing it
 * to SVG (in a file) and to PROVN (on the console).
 * 
 * @author lucmoreau
 * @see <a href="http://blog.provbook.org/2013/10/11/a-little-provenance-goes-a-long-way/">a-little-provenance-goes-a-long-way blog post</a>
 */
public class Little {


    public static final String PROVBOOK_NS = "http://www.provbook.org";
    public static final String PROVBOOK_PREFIX = "provbook";

    public static final String JIM_PREFIX = "jim", TRUNG_PREFIX = "trung";
    public static final String JIM_NS = "http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~hendler/", TRUNG_NS = "abcd";

    private final ProvFactory pFactory;
    private final Namespace ns;
    public Little(ProvFactory pFactory) {
        this.pFactory = pFactory;
        ns=new Namespace();
        ns.addKnownNamespaces();
        ns.register(PROVBOOK_PREFIX, PROVBOOK_NS);
        ns.register(JIM_PREFIX, JIM_NS);
        ns.register(TRUNG_PREFIX, TRUNG_NS);
    }

    public QualifiedName qn(String n) {
        return ns.qualifiedName(PROVBOOK_PREFIX, n, pFactory);
    }

    public Document makeDocument() {     
        /***********Testing code************/
        Entity book = pFactory.newEntity(ns.qualifiedName(TRUNG_PREFIX, "PROV Definition", pFactory));
        Agent trung = pFactory.newAgent(qn("Trung"), "Trung Nguyen");
        WasAttributedTo attr3 = pFactory.newWasAttributedTo(null,
                                                            book.getId(),
                                                            trung.getId());     
         /********************************/

        Entity quote = pFactory.newEntity(qn("a-little-provenance-goes-a-long-way"));
        //quote.setValue(pFactory.newValue("A little provenance goes a long way",
          //                               pFactory.getName().XSD_STRING));
        Agent paul = pFactory.newAgent(qn("Paul"), "Paul Groth");
        WasAttributedTo attr1 = pFactory.newWasAttributedTo(null,
                quote.getId(),
                paul.getId());


        Entity original = pFactory.newEntity(ns.qualifiedName(JIM_PREFIX,"LittleSemanticsWeb.html",pFactory));       
        Agent luc = pFactory.newAgent(qn("Luc"), "Luc Moreau");
        WasAttributedTo attr2 = pFactory.newWasAttributedTo(null,
                                                            quote.getId(),
                                                            luc.getId());


        WasDerivedFrom wdf = pFactory.newWasDerivedFrom(quote.getId(), original.getId());        
        WasDerivedFrom wdf1 = pFactory.newWasDerivedFrom(book.getId(), quote.getId());


        Document document = pFactory.newDocument();
        document.getStatementOrBundle()
                .addAll(Arrays.asList(new StatementOrBundle[] { quote,
                                                                book,
                                                                trung,
                                                                luc,
                                                                paul,
                                                                attr1,
                                                                attr2, 
                                                                attr3,
                                                                original,                                                                
                                                                wdf,
                                                                wdf1}));
        document.setNamespace(ns);
        return document;
    }

    public void doConversions(Document document, String file) {
        InteropFramework intF=new InteropFramework();
        intF.writeDocument(file, document);     
        intF.writeDocument(System.out, ProvFormat.PROVN, document);
        //intF.writeDocument("trang.txt", document);

        //System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n*********Get Doc's Elements****************");
        //Document trung_doc = intF.readDocumentFromFile("trung.provn");
        //Document trung_doc = intF.readDocumentFromFile("ss_expanded_prov.provn");
        Document trung_doc = intF.readDocumentFromFile("ss_reputation_binding.provn");

        List temp = trung_doc.getStatementOrBundle();
        System.out.println(temp.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            //System.out.println(temp.get(i).getStatement().size());

            if (temp.get(i) instanceof Entity){
                Entity temp_ent = (Entity) temp.get(i);
                System.out.println("\nEntity's Attributes:");
                System.out.println("Entity "+ i +": ");
                System.out.println("Value: "+temp_ent.getValue());
                System.out.println("Other: "+temp_ent.getOther());
                System.out.println("Type: "+temp_ent.getType());
                System.out.println("Label: "+temp_ent.getLabel());
                System.out.println("Location: "+temp_ent.getLocation());
                System.out.println("ID: "+temp_ent.getId());
                System.out.println("Kind: "+temp_ent.getKind());                                
            }
        }                

        System.out.println("*************************");
    }

    public void closingBanner() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*************************");
    }

    public void openingBanner() {
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println("* Converting document  ");
        System.out.println("*************************");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        if (args.length!=1) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("main to be called with filename");
        String file=args[0];

        Little little=new Little(InteropFramework.newXMLProvFactory());
        little.openingBanner();
        Document document = little.makeDocument();
        little.doConversions(document, file);
        little.closingBanner();

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the provenance JAR on your classpath when you compile and run?

Comment: Without NamedBundle it's all working fine. NamedBundle, Entity, WasDerivedFrom, etc. are all from the `package org.openprovenance.prov.model` so it's unreasonable if it doesn't work if NamedBundle is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try importing

```
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.Bundle;
```

instead of

```
import org.openprovenance.prov.model.NamedBundle;
```

I can see a commit comment : renamed NamedBundle to Bundle (and Bundle to BundleEntity)

https://github.com/lucmoreau/ProvToolbox/commit/b6053f8ba8f5762c1d7d64aae79a5d7f0de2046a